# Create a vector of random integers that only occur once with numpy / Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I would like to get an array of integers in a certain range. But every number must occur once. Is there a possibility to do this as a simple one liner or simple command ?

Till now I only found

```
np.random.choice(10,10)
```

or

```
np.random.randint(1,10,9)
```

But both of these functions do not give back a vector where every number only occurs once.

Hint: I know that Iam not allowed to ask for more numbers than there is compared to the range.

Comment: Use `replace=False` in it as the optional arg.

Comment: Thank you, this only worked with the choice command, do you know why ?

Comment: Because `np.random.randint` isn't meant for such a task.